# Why isn't read_csv() parsing my dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running pandas 0.7.0.  I have a file with lines like:

```
2014-01-12T00:00:00+00:00, 0.210079
```

When I read that with

```
data = pd.read_csv('xx', names=["t", "p"], parse_dates=[0])
```

I end up with the first column being strings.  Why aren't they getting parsed into datetimes?

```
print data.head()
                           t         p
0  2014-01-12T00:00:00+00:00  0.210079
1  2014-01-12T00:00:00+00:00  0.078217
2  2014-01-12T00:00:00+00:00  0.342977
3  2014-01-12T00:00:00+00:00  0.346713
4  2014-01-12T00:00:00+00:00  0.224601
```

Comment: Don't use print to check for data types. Please check output of `data.dtypes` instead, and post here if `t`'s type differs from `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: As stated above, I'm running pandas 0.7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is getting **parsed correctly**:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", names=["t", "p"], parse_dates=[0])
>>> data.to_dict()
{'p': {0: 0.21007899999999999}, 't': {0: Timestamp('2014-01-12 00:00:00', tz=None)}}
>>>
```

You'll note about that the date you've mentioned in your data (*I used a sample based on your question*) is a `Timestamp` obhect which seems to represent the data parsed.

**Update:**

After more investigating at the Python shell using `dir()` I've found even more evidence that it is correctly parsed as a date/time object (`Timestamp` in this case):

```
>>> data.to_dict()["t"][0]
Timestamp('2014-01-12 00:00:00', tz=None)
>>> dir(data.to_dict()["t"][0])
['__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__pyx_vtable__', '__qualname__', '__radd__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rsub__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_field', '_repr_base', 'asm8', 'astimezone', 'combine', 'ctime', 'date', 'day', 'dayofweek', 'dayofyear', 'dst', 'freq', 'freqstr', 'fromordinal', 'fromtimestamp', 'hour', 'isocalendar', 'isoformat', 'isoweekday', 'max', 'microsecond', 'min', 'minute', 'month', 'nanosecond', 'now', 'offset', 'quarter', 'replace', 'resolution', 'second', 'strftime', 'strptime', 'time', 'timetuple', 'timetz', 'to_datetime', 'to_period', 'to_pydatetime', 'today', 'toordinal', 'tz', 'tz_convert', 'tz_localize', 'tzinfo', 'tzname', 'utcfromtimestamp', 'utcnow', 'utcoffset', 'utctimetuple', 'value', 'week', 'weekday', 'weekofyear', 'year']
>>> data.to_dict()["t"][0].timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=12, tm_isdst=-1)
>>>
```

By the way... If you do `print data.head()` this is printing to screen a representation of the object being returned by `data.head()`. This may be your source of confusion, but it is only a representation. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html

Comment: That's not what I get.


    >>> data = pd.read_csv("xx1", names=["t", "p"], parse_dates=[0])
    >>> data.to_dict()
    {'p': {0: 0.21007899999999999}, 't': {0: '2014-01-12T00:00:00+00:00'}}
    >>> data.to_dict()["t"][0].timetuple()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'timetuple'

Comment: @RoySmith I'd recommend you upgrade your version of pandas. I tested with the latest version and it "worked".

Comment: I just upgraded to 0.12.0 (wow, I didn't realize I was so far behind on versions).  Works now.  Thanks!